# Spring Boot / JUnit Integration Tests with multiple In-Memory Databases

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, junit

Is it possible to create Spring Boot / JUnit Integration Tests with multiple In-Memory Databases? If possible how to do so, any resources on it? (I couldn't find any)

Answer (score 0):

You can try H2 DB. They declare multiple schemas support.

The connection could be like this to initialize schemas.

`jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=create schema if not exists test\;runscript from '~/sql/init.sql'`

Then you can declare two DataSources for each schema. Or if you need to start 2 SpringBoot applications you can define 2 different configs and run both application on different ports and contexts

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ServicesIntegrationTest {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void runTest() throws Exception {
        SpringApplicationBuilder uws = new SpringApplicationBuilder(UserWebApplication.class)
                .properties("server.port=8081",
                        "server.contextPath=/UserService");
        uws.run();
        SpringApplicationBuilder pws = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ProjectWebApplication.class)
                .properties("server.port=8082",
                        "server.contextPath=/ProjectService");
        pws.run();

        String url = "http://localhost:8081/UserService/users";
```

The test I used here https://github.com/StanislavLapitsky/SpringSOAProxy/blob/master/soa-integration/src/test/java/org/proxysoa/spring/controller/ServicesIntegrationTest.java

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I can tell the code snippet starts a new spring application. What I want to archive is to start / create a 2nd in-memory db in one spring application. However I don't know if its really worth it since you could just create the required tables in the existing db.